# What is the Object of a Activity called by an Intent

Tags: android, class, android-intent

i want to know what the Object of an Activity is when i started it by an Intent.

This means: How can i call the Object of the active Activity. Or did I get something wrong and an Activity istn represented by an Object?

Example: In MainActivity i do:

```
ShowExampleScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExampleClass.class);
startActivity(ShowExampleScreen);

public class ExampleClass{

    oncreate( Stuff in on create)

    public void myFunction(){ my stuff} 
}
```

How can i use myFunc in other class without declaring it static?
How can i get the Object of the Activity which is started by the Intent?

Comment: why do you need the object of the activity started by the Intent. When the Intent is fired, it will launch the Activity denoted by ExampleClass. Make sure ExampleClass extends Activity and declare it in the manifest file

Comment: yes, the activity starts as wished, but for example when i want myFunc to be a textfield setter class and i want to call it from somewhere else i have to create an Object of ExampleClass. I want this Object to be the Object launched by the Intent so i can set the textviews shown at the activites view

Comment: What are you expecting as an answer? You shouldn't be calling activity methods from other activities

Comment: What you're asking isn't really feasible.  Considering passing the values of "my stuff" as an Intent extra so the activity can do something with it.

Comment: Im sorry, im pretty new to android and doin my first steps. So you would say, ill do a class where i do the calculation and textview  stuff and in the view i just refer to these Objects then?

Comment: You would normally transfer you rvalues within the Intent.
Refer to that: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it, here are a couple of them that I use:

- From another class/method:

  just pass the Activity as a parameter, since you want the most recent activity object, you don't want to store it somewhere where it can become null once the activity is destroyed.
- From a method that is very deep in other classes:

  I don't really recommend this but I do this sometimes, just create a static object of the activity in the Activity itself and make sure you assign it every time the activity is renewed, let's say in the onResume method or onCreate

  ```
  public static Activity app; //in your Activity as a field (instance variable)

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      app = this;
   }
  ```
- From a fragment:

  MyActivity app = (MyActivity) getActivity(); //getActivity() is a Fragment method.

Comment: Thank you, i think the first one is the answer. I it figured out now by creating a underlaying data storage class from wich i create a object when main Activity starts. My second screen activity then just collects the Data out of the underlaying Data object. So i dont need to handle with this Activity Object stuff. Can you tell me which Method is the "cleaner" way?

Comment: The best way is to pass as argument as all time. It is the safest way, but sometimes you need another way, so it's up to you but you need to be careful and document it well.

Answer (score 0):

In Android this is how the Activity life cycle works:
[image]

I would recommend you to begin [reading from here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to get the fundamentals cleared first.

As per the guidelines, you **SHOULD NOT** invoke the method of one Activity from the other

However, you can use `startActivityForResult` . ie You can launch the Activity and get result back.  [See this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) for the implementation